# How to clean up subscriptions in react components? (Hooks)

Tags: reactjs

Consider this code below:

```js
import React , { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Row , Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Product from '../components/Product'
import axios from 'axios'

const HomeScreen = () =>{
    const [products , setProducts]  = useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchProducts = async () =>{
            const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/products')
            setProducts(data)
        }
        fetchProducts()
    },[products])
    return(
        <>
        <h2 className='my-3'>Latest Products</h2>
        <Row>
            {
                products.map((product)=>(
                    <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Product product={product} rating = {product.rating} reviews={product.numReviews}/>
                    </Col>
                ))
            }
        </Row>
        </>
    )
}
export default HomeScreen
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React , {useState , useEffect} from 'react'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import axios from 'axios'


const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
    const [product , setProduct] = useState({})
    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchProduct = async ()=>{
            const {data} = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
            setProduct(data)
        }
        fetchProduct()
    },[match])
    return (
        <>
            <Link className='btn btn-light my-3' to='/'>
            Go Back
            </Link>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Rating rating={product.rating} reviews={product.numReviews}/>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                <strong> Price: ${product.price}</strong>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item>
                    <strong>Description :</strong> {product.description}
                </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Card>
                        <ListGroup>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Price :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                    Status :
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                    <strong>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In Stock' : "Out Of Stock"}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item className='d-grid gap-2'>
                                <Button type='button' disabled={product.countInStock === 0}>
                                    Add To Cart
                                </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item>
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The issue is that I see "products" renders twice.

the error message is

> "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is
> a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix,
> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup
> function."

How can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean `see "products" renders twice`? Are you logging that string somewhere? Or do you mean the products data is literally rendering twice in the DOM?

Comment: Can you show the whole component?

Comment: I mean that when I reload my page, I see an error that says product is undefined so after I dig deeper I realized it rendered twice because of the useEffect hook.

Comment: Done I have edit my post and added the whole component with the error message

Comment: I think you maybe should remove the products in the useEffect dependency.

Comment: Your component might be unmounted by the time your axios call returns, so you should make sure that hasn't happened before you call `setProducts` (between await axios and setProducts). You can do this (as the error says and as [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) say) by returning a cleanup function from your effect that sets a flag like unmounted = true (or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

It's a memory leak issue. The memory leak will happen if the API server or host took some time to respond and the component was unmounted before the response was received. To avoid this issue , you can keep a boolean flag , like **componentMounted = false** . So the code portion will look like below

```
useEffect(() => {
  let componentMounted = true;
    const response = async () => {
     // API calling
      if(componentMounted) {
        setData(response?.data); // null checking
      }
    };
    fetchData();
    return () => { // using return avoids the memory leak issue
     componentMounted = false;
    }
  }, []);
```

The boolean flag cleans the previous effect when new effect will be executed. There are other methods to do this like using **AbortController** to abort the request or **useStateSafe** hook etc.

Comment: I have done the exact thing you mentioned but unfortuently the error still presist.

Comment: Share your code in the sandbox. and share the link